# Hide a password on argv from ps or who

Tags: linux

So I'm working to hide the password from the `ps -aux` list, or `w` list in linux.

I'm using rlwrap and sqlplus, connecting thusly:

```
rlwrap sqlplus user/pass@connect_identifier
```

And it shows my pass in plaintext in the `who` list.

Anyone know how I can make it so that it does not show the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer shamelessly stolen from  [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/2180/5679/0/))

You can invoke sqlplus with something like:

```
rlwrap sqlplus internal @/path/to/script
```

where `/path/to/script` contains `connect user/pass@connect_identifier`; and has permissions such that a normal user can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to prompt for a password, read it from stdin or a file, or get it from an environment variable.  However if you really want to change what is shown by `ps` you can use a function commonly called `setproctitle()`.  On some BSD systems this is in the C library, but there are [various](http://git.kernel.org/?p=utils/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng.git;a=blob;f=lib/setproctitle.c) [other implementations](http://anoncvs.mindrot.org/index.cgi/openssh/openbsd-compat/setproctitle.c?view=markup).  Of course, if you do this then there is still a brief period where another user could see the original arguments before you change them.